# Apache2: error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, apache2, lets-encrypt

Without any reason my Apache2 Webserver on Ubuntu stopped working. Every HTTPS site i want to open I get "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". When I call on my server 'openssl s_client -connect www.kosa-strick.com:443 -state -debug' I get:

```
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
140122828576408:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
```

VHOST-Config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.kosa-strick.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@kosa-strick.com
        Redirect / https://www.kosa-strick.com/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kosa_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kosa_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.kosa-strick.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@kosa-strick.com

        <Directory /var/www/kosa/kosa-strick-website/public_html>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/kosa/kosa-strick-website/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kosa_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/kosa_access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kosa-strick.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.kosa-strick.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

SSL Config File is:

```
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined
#LogLevel warn
#ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Always ensure Cookies have "Secure" set (JAH 2012/1)
#Header edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*)(;\s*secure)??((\s*;)?(.*)) "$1; Secure$3$4"
```

I did no config change or update or whatever. It simply stopped working.
Rebooting server didn't help.

Logfile says:

```
[Thu May 16 12:44:42.444514 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10992] AH01916: Init: (yewsvr1.yewstone.io:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Thu May 16 12:44:42.494285 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10993] AH01916: Init: (yewsvr1.yewstone.io:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
[Thu May 16 12:44:42.495892 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10993] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 16 12:44:42.495922 2019] [core:notice] [pid 10993] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

But this is bullshit. The port configuration worked for years and was never changed and the ports.conf is correct:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   yewsvr1.yewstone.io:443... You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port! ...
```

> But this is bullshit

If Apache says this then this is how it sees your configuration and it is likely not bullshit. My guess is that the error is in a part of the configuration you don't show, i.e. in the configuration of  yewsvr1.yewstone.io. It is sufficient if one of the vhosts on the same IP and port is improperly configured to cause the problems you see.

Comment: A VHOST named "yewsvr1.yewstone.io" doesn't exist. I checked all VHOST config files and they are all fine and untouched since about two months. But the error occures sind today morning.

Comment: @Philipp: you provide only a snippet of your configuration where you think the problem is but as I said the problem is likely at a different place. Given that the error message of the web server explicitly refers to this name it is very likely that it somehow uses a configuration for this name. It is unlikely that it just makes up this name. So the chance is high that there is some part of the configuration you are not aware of and which you don't include here but which is causing the trouble.